# Rewrite or change MAIL FROM:<> with postfix or mailman

Tags: postfix, mailman

I've got a problem with laposte.net free french email provider : since several weeks now, their smtp servers don't accept empty `MAIL FROM` anymore. Here is a sample telnet session :

```
$ telnet smtpz4.laposte.net 25
Trying 194.117.213.1...
Connected to smtpz4.laposte.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 lpn-prd-vrin016 ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
HELO XX.XXXXX.XXX
250 lpn-prd-vrin016
MAIL FROM:<>
501 5.0.1 Emetteur invalide. Invalid Sender. LPN007_403
421 4.7.0 lpn-prd-vrin016 Error: too many errors
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I know that it is mandatory to accept these emails, and I've contacted them several times, without any luck.

The problem for me is for mailman mailing lists : as the messages are sent with an empty `MAIL FROM`, they are all rejected for `laposte.net` adresses (other domains work fine).

Do you know a workaround, either as a Mailman configuration option or maybe with a Postfix specific rewrite rule, to change the empty `MAIL FROM` for mails sent to this domain ?

**EDIT :** Here is the complete headers of a mail sent by Mailman (version 2.1.15 on my system) :

```
From - Wed Oct 15 17:08:30 2014
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys: 
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Delivered-To: xxxxxx@ww.xxxxx.org
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by ww.xxxxx.org (Postfix) with SMTP id 85104248A2
for <xxxxxx@ww.xxxxx.org>; Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:02:34 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from ns279475.ip-91-121-90.eu (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by ww.xxxxx.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id D5E342082D;
Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:02:33 +0200 (CEST)
X-Original-To: rize.infos@xxxxx.org
Delivered-To: rize.infos@ww.xxxxx.org
Received: from [IPv6:2a01:e34:ec12:8fe0:cd70:60bd:95b3:1f48] (unknown
[IPv6:2a01:e34:ec12:8fe0:cd70:60bd:95b3:1f48])
(Authenticated sender: xxxxxx)
by ww.xxxxx.org (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 024CC2082D
for <rize.infos@xxxxx.org>; Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:02:04 +0200 (CEST)
Message-ID: <543A519B.2070003@yyyyyyy.org>
Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:02:03 +0200
From: =?UTF-8?B?V2VibWFzdGVyIMOJY29sZSBkZSBsYSBSaXpl?=
<webmaster@yyyyyyy.org>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/31.1.2
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: rize.infos@xxxxx.org
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------------080100040705040508010509"
X-Mailman-Approved-At: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:02:32 +0200
Subject: [xxxx xxxxx] xxxxxxxxxxx
X-BeenThere: rize.infos@xxxxx.org
X-Mailman-Version: 2.1.15
Precedence: list
List-Id: <rize.infos.xxxxx.org>
List-Unsubscribe: <http://xxxxx.org/cgi-bin/mailman/options/rize.infos>;,
<mailto:rize.infos-request@xxxxx.org?subject=unsubscribe>
List-Post: <mailto:rize.infos@xxxxx.org>
List-Help: <mailto:rize.infos-request@xxxxx.org?subject=help>
List-Subscribe: <http://xxxxx.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rize.infos>;,
<mailto:rize.infos-request@xxxxx.org?subject=subscribe>
Errors-To: rize.infos-bounces@xxxxx.org
```

Comment: I don't understand why you state mailman send email with MAIL FROM <>, AFAIK mailman would use <listname-bounces> as MAIL FROM value.

Comment: In my `mail.log` file mailman seems to send mails with `MAIL FROM:<>`, like this : `postfix/qmgr[6225]: BAFA124577: from=<>, size=15428, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

Comment: Could you edit the question and adding the full header of email sent by mailman? Also please provide information about mailman version in your host

Comment: @masegaloeh Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [PCRE map for Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html). It allows you to define mail from rewrites for addresses based on a regular expression.